# How to pass parameter in scheduler cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Can some body find me a way how can i pass argument while making scheduler call in cocos2d or cocos2dx? I'm using this scheduler call and passing it parameter by a class variable. I want to send parameter through this call. Thanks!

scheduler->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(CFacebookManager::sendRequestAllUpdateUI), CFacebookManager::instance(), 1, false, 1, 1.0f);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cocos2dx with c++11, I had to make an action that takes a lambda of code and schedules it. Lamdas can capture any number of variables, plus the action takes userData as a template, and passes it to the lambda as a pointer, so you can modify it and expect percistency across updates without declaring extra instance variables in your class.
Please, check it out.
https://github.com/radif/MCBCallLambda

Comment: This has been quite helpful to me indeed. Finally able to pass parameters in c++ under cocos2dx. Thanks Radif!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do isn't possible in cocos2d. You can't pass parameter's through a schedule update method.

LearnCocos2d gave a good answers to almost the same question here [schedule event with multiple arguments in cocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464226/schedule-event-with-multiple-arguments-in-cocos2d)